# Azure deployment source not showing private repository from BitBucket

Tags: azure, bitbucket

I have a private repository hosted on BitBucket. On Azure I have created a web app and in the app service I want to set a deployment source to my BitBucket instance.

The authorization was ok, but when I want to select a project, the list shows no results.

What can be the issue here ?

**Update**: it looks like an authorization issue, because when opening the list of branches using the rest api, i get a forbidden result: https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{org}/{repo}/branches

When the admin of my repo is available I'll ask for admin permission and update this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a permission issue. To have deployment source attached to a BitBucket instance, you need admin rights on the repository.